# Building docker image in gitlabCI pipeline with tags

Tags: docker

I am have been using the standard docker in docker approach to build custom docker images and I was wondering if there was a way to modify the .gitlab-ci.yml to build tags.

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# Official docker image.
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info | grep Registr
  - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY

build-master:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
  only:
    - master

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  except:
    - master
```

Personally, I think the new features in docker hub make this really easy to do in github, but I but existing repo is in gitlab. Any examples would be amazing, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are able to build tags just by specifying tags in your conditionals.

For example:

```
only:
  - tags
```

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding I want to tag docker images with tags not build on taags.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. 
This is supported but Gitlab needs to pull the image from the remote registry first. You can see the following for an example: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/23/gitlab-container-registry

    `release-image:
        stage: release
        script:
           - docker pull $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
           - docker tag $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
           - docker push $CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE
         only:
           - master`